# Application crashes upon new Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-manifest

I know and I do understand that this question has been asked, but I can't seem to interpret it for my application. I am creating an application - using Android Studio - that opens a Activity (called 'About'). When a user clicks on the 'about button' on my MainActivity, it should launch the 'About' activity. However, when I test this out on my device, it says the app has stopped. And on my output panel, it says something about an error with my Manifest.xml file?

MainActivity:

```
package com.msp.supercarsounds;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


public void clickedAbout(View view) {

    final int result = 1;

    Intent AboutButtonClicked = new Intent (this, About.class);
    AboutButtonClicked.putExtra("About", "MainActivity");
    startActivityForResult(AboutButtonClicked, result);

}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.msp.supercarsounds">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17"
              android:targetSdkVersion="22"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: You didn't add an entry for `About` activity in your AndroidManifest...

Comment: @Karakuri - Thank you so much! My application is now working!

Comment: No problem. For the future, the first thing you should do when you have a crash is go to logcat and find the stack trace. If you can't determine the cause and how to fix it based on that and a reasonable amount of web searching, then you should post a question including the entire stack trace. In this case there should be an exception message that the target activity could not be found and to make sure you declared it in your  AndroidManifest.

Comment: @Karakuri - I will certainly do that the next time! Thank you so much, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare **About** activity

```
<activity android:name=".About">
    </activity>
```

Add this below the `</activity>` tag of **MainActivity**

Answer (score 0):

your second  activity "about" is not added to manifest.xml add this under the mainactivity

```
   <activity android:name=".about">/activity>
```